Shared pointer pass by value makes count as 0 on mac and 1 on win
I saw that Shared pointer pass by value  makes count as 0 on mac but remains as 1 on window for my code.
So I have been trying to understand shared pointer pass by value and pass by reference by listening to the talk  reference talk . This was referenced in some other stack overflow link here
I have tried to understand the fundamentals by coding here https://godbolt.org/z/1vd53eEhM
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void f(shared_ptr<int> sp) {
  
  ///sp.reset();
}

int main() {
  // Create a shared pointer.
  shared_ptr<int> sp = make_shared<int>(10);

  // Pass the shared pointer to the function by value.
  f(sp);

  // The original shared pointer has lost ownership of the object.
  cout << "testing (should be 0) "<< sp.use_count() << endl; // Prints 0

  return 0;
}

The expected output should have been 0 but I get it as 1.
What did I miss on the loss of the ownership part in pass by value?

Why do you think it should be zero? sp still owns an int. The other owner giving up its ownership has no effect on any of the other owners. (Suppose we own a car together. If I give up my part of the ownership, the car doesn't disappear but is all yours.)

If you change your function to void bar(std::shared_ptr<int>& sp), then yes, you will modify sp, and the reference count will be 0, because there will be no managed object. In your example you are sp.reset() on a copy of sp from main.

i removed sp.reset .
Now it should be 0 right ?

"I saw that Shared pointer pass by value makes count as 0 on mac but remains as 1 on window for my code." are you absolutetly sure that this is the code you compiled and ran on mac to see a 0 output ? If yes, please provide us more details about the used compiler and the complier flags

"Now it should be 0 right ?" why? no. Same comment of molbdnilo still applies. If you have two owners then one owner doing something does not affect the other (unless you forcefully destroy the object, which your code isnt doing). Thats the reason to use a shared pointer in the first place

please do not change the code on the fly. This reduces crediblity a lot . You write you observed some output with some code and you expected some other output. Now you edited the code only but the statements about output you see and you expect is the same. How can that be?

That sp.reset went in by mistake as i was experimenting different things hence i removed that

thats why I asked you to please again confirm that this is the code you compiled and ran to see different outputs on mac and windows. Modifying the code wasnt the reply I was expecting ;)

Any number of shared_ptr  can be pointing to the same object; use_count gives you the number of shared_ptr that are still pointing to the same object. Which, of course, includes your own -- so unless your pointer is pointing to no object at all, the use_count is at least 1. If you print the count inside your function, you get 2 because you've made a copy of the shared_ptr, so now there are two that point to the same int.

The posted code (with sp passed by value) - whether with or without sp.reset(); - should report a use_count() of 1 in main (see demo). I cannot see how it can possibly report 0 on Mac or any other system. Please make sure you use this actual version for testing.

The key here is shared; multiple shared_ptr objects share ownership of the same object. To have only one owner you'd use unique_ptr.


// The original shared pointer has lost ownership of the object.


No, it did not.
When calling f(sp);, sp is getting copied, so that both the original sp and the copy within f share ownership.
Temporarily, the use_count() would be 2.
When you're printing sp.use_count() later, the copy of sp no longer exists, but sp still exists and has not lost its ownership.
A call to sp.reset() within f would also have no effect on the original sp within main.
A loss of ownership would only occur when you move (not copy) sp:
f(std::move(sp)); // the sp parameter object gains ownership, and our sp loses ownership

sp could also have its ownership revoked if it was passed by reference (which it isn't):
void f(shared_ptr<int>& sp) {
    // "action at a distance"
    // the sp within main now loses its ownership
    sp.reset();
}

However, passing smart pointer by reference is something you generally don't do.
You should not see any difference between Mac and Windows regarding this behavior.
Perhaps you have over-simplified your example so that the issue is no longer reproducible, or the original code was multi-threaded, in which case use_count() is more of a guess than the guaranteed current value.
